# Rails way (query) to get the Posts which a user hasn't read or there are new Replies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a forum. Every User has Posts and Replies. Every Post has Replies. Whenever a user views a post I create a record in a Views table (or update it with the last reply_id). Lets say a Post doesn't have any replies yet, then I just save the user_id and post_id. If there are replies to a post, then I save the user_id, post_id, and the reply_id of the last reply at the time of the post view.

I am trying to create a page "Search unread posts" that shows a user any posts they haven't read, or if there is a new reply to a post they already viewed. I am sure that most of you are familiar with this principal because most forum engines have this kind of search, but I wanted to make sure not to leave any questions open.

Here are the associations (stripped of all permission checks and other associations):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :views
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :replies
  has_many :views
  has_one :latest_reply, :order => "created_at DESC", :class_name => "Reply", :conditions => { :replystatus => 'published' }
end

class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :views
end

class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :reply
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to know how to only get the posts that the user, either, hasn't read at all (no record in Views), or the posts latest_reply.id is bigger than the one saved in Views. I have figured out how to write this query in sql (with joins, subqueries and a union), but I would like to know if anyone would know a way to do this the Rails way. I am guessing that a few smart (chained) scopes will work, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer

Based on OP's comments I realized I misunderstood the question in former answer. The read/unread tracking is so deep to the user level. I don't have such experience but could provide two thoughts for brainstorming.

1. Database way. You keep what you do now. But for every new post created, you add records for each user in to the View table with initial value of zero view count for each user. By this you can use SQL to check which posts are unread for certain user. The drawback is the server workload will be heavy and the table will be huge, maybe you can use cron to add View records and use cache to store user's unread posts.
2. Array comparing way. You add a field to user table store the post ids a user viewed. For every posts he viewed, the field will be updated with added post id. Then, when you show a normal list of posts(say recent posts), you can compare if this id is in this field(converted to array), if not, mark the post as unread. To show a full list of unread posts, you use a SQL to search posts ids not in this field (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE id NOT IN the_id_list_arrary)

Feel free to criticize.

#### Abandoned former answer due to misunderstanding of question

My suggestion is to add a field named `view_count` in Post with default value of 0.

Every time you write to `View` table with a new record about Post, you increment `view_count` by 1 as well.

To search unread posts, you can simply search posts with view_count of 0.

By this method you'll save lots of server resource on querying, because the View table will be very big and querying it the way in your question is very heavy.

Optional future enhancement:

1. You can design a task to rebuild the view_count through View table, and run it either manually or by cron.
2. You can even add view_count_month, view_count_year, view_count_all fields as you like in the future. With the rebuild mechanism, maintaining these fields would be easy.

After all, in my opinion the basic solution should be good enough.

Comment: Rails supports a :counter_cache mechanism to do this automatically.  It is implemented by adding :counter_cache => true as an option to the  belongs_to :post.  Additionally, a views_count column is required on the Post table. Subsequently, you can call something like: post.views.size.zero?  More details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache

Comment: I already have a postviews column on my Post table to keep track of the overall views of a post. The View table I described in my questions is purely to keep track of the views on a per user basis.

Comment: So lets say we have 3 users (Joe, Mike, and Tom) and Joe has not read any posts, therefore he doesn't have any record in Views. Mike has read a post and all the replies in it, so Mike has a record in Views with his user_id, the post_id, and the reply_id of the last reply of that post. Tom has read the post, but he only read the first page of the replies, so his View record shows the user_id, post_id, and the reply_id of the last reply on page one.

Comment: @tomthorgal, I misunderstood that, check my new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment for @BillyChan re: Post and view count.

Re: latest_reply, I think you should push that down into the Reply model as a scope:

```
scope :latest, order('created_at DESC').first
scope :published, where(:replystatus => 'published')
```

Subsequently, you can access it as post.views.published.latest / reply.views.published.latest and compare however you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mediate table is a right way, but it is often too heavy to handle, even with counter caching or other stuff (just imagine the million or records in the View table...).

So I can offer a much lighter and faster option without any connection tables.

```
User has_many Posts and Replies
Posts has_many Replies
```

Post has an attribute: `last_viewed` (datetime). And each time when User got view the post's replies, attribute is get updated to a particular reply's `created_at` value (if it newer).

Now:

```
Reply.includes(:post => :user).where(["users.id = ? AND posts.last_viewed < replies.created_at", @user.id]) # all replies belongs_to post, which ones the post's author (user) has never seen.

# and

Post.includes(:replies).where(["posts.user_id = ? AND posts.last_viewed < replies.created_at", @user.id]) # all user's posts having replies, which he has never seen.
```

This approach is used most often in the forum engines. Because it is fast.

**[update]** All users and all posts and all replies:

Add an attribute to User: `last_view_posts_at` (datetime)
That attribute must be updated with Post's or Reply's `created_at` value (if newer) when the user open it.

```
Reply.includes(:post).where(["posts.created_at > ? OR replies.created_at > ?", @user.last_view_posts_at.to_s(:db)]) # all replies which the @user has never seen.

# and

Post.includes(:replies).where(["posts.created_at > ? OR replies.created_at > ?", @user.last_view_posts_at.to_s(:db)]) # all unseen posts and post having unseen replies.
```

The problem is you can not manage read/unread for particular post and reply, because it depends on a timestamp. You have to play with `last_view_posts_at'. Imagine you have 3 unread messages. After that you open the oldest, then read the newest, in that case the 2nd one (middle) will not be 'unread' anymore.

Comment: Well. But it handles only my own posts, but question was about all posts.

Comment: Can't understand. Give example, please!

Comment: What if there are 2 posts I didn't see. I open the newest... Second one get lost from `not seen`...

Comment: yes, this is The main disadvantage. You can not manage read/unread for particular post and reply, because it depends on date. You have to play with `last_view_posts_at'.

Comment: if you open the newest, another would be older then `last_view_posts_at' anyway. The problem is when you you have 3 unread messages, then read the newest, then read the oldest, and the 2nd (middle) get lost from 'not seen'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fine tune the actual query that serves my question asked. Here is the actual query (user_id is hardcoded in this example, but in the controller it is @current_user.id):

```
select posts.id, posts.title
  from posts
 where posts.id not in (
        select p.id
          from (select posts.id, max(replies.id)
              from posts
              left outer join replies on replies.post_id = posts.id
             group by posts.id
            INTERSECT
            select views.post_id, views.reply_id
              from views
             where views.user_id = 1 ) as p )
```

And here is how I have it in my controller (will move it in to the model as a scope):

```
@posts = Post.includes(:latest_reply).where('posts.id not in ( select p.id from (select posts.id, max(replies.id) from posts left outer join replies on replies.post_id = posts.id group by posts.id INTERSECT select views.post_id, views.reply_id from views where views.user_id = ? ) as p )', @current_user.id).page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

I know that it isn't pretty, but I've been trying to figure out how to do this "Rails Way" for almost two days now and it just has to do for now because I have lots more coding to do :)

If anyone has any tips or how to do this the "Rails Way" or how to speed up this query (it is surprisingly fast) I'd appreciate all your input.